# How can I parse anyType {----} response with ksoap2

Tags: android, json, service, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing ksoap2 response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092424/parsing-ksoap2-response)

I have seen many forum questions about this, but i haven't found a solution that works for me. 
THis is my code:

```
String serviceURL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/WebService.asmx";
                 String serviceNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
                 String serviceMethod = "getUser";
                 String SoapAction = "http://tempuri.org/getUser";
                 SoapObject SoapObj = new SoapObject(serviceNamespace,serviceMethod);
                    SoapObj.newInstance ();
                    SoapObj.addProperty ("uname", "Evv");
                   // SoapObj.addProperty ("uposy", "333");
                    //SoapObj.addProperty ("uposx", "333");                 
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new                        SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                 envelope.bodyOut = SoapObj;
                 envelope.dotNet = true;
                 envelope.implicitTypes = true;
                 envelope.encodingStyle = "utf-8";
                 envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2001;
                 envelope.xsd = SoapEnvelope.XSD;
                 envelope.xsi = SoapEnvelope.XSI;
                 AndroidHttpTransport ht = new AndroidHttpTransport(serviceURL);
                 //Initiate Connection


                 try 
                  {
                  ht.debug = true;
                  ht.call (SoapAction, envelope);
                   SoapObject response=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                      tv.setText(response);
```

}

Is the anyType{uposx=222; uposy=222;} a JSON-response? I can see it written out in the textview, but i want to parse it.

I have tried with JSON Object, but not gotten it to work:

```
 JSONObject JSONObj;
                  JSONArray JSONArr;
                   SoapObject res = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                   gets our result in JSON String
                  String ResultObject = response.getProperty(0).toString();

                  if (ResultObject.startsWith("anyType{")) { // if JSON string is an object
                      JSONObj = new JSONObject(ResultObject);

   Iterator<String> itr = JSONObj.keys();
                      while (itr.hasNext()) {
                          String Key = (String) itr.next();
                          String Value = JSONObj.getString(Key);
                          bundleResult.putString(Key, Value);
                          tv.setText(bundleResult.getString(Key));

                      }
                  } else if (ResultObject.startsWith("anyType{")) { // if JSON string is an array
                      JSONArr = new JSONArray(ResultObject);
                      tv.setText("length" + JSONArr.length());
                      for (int i = 0; i < JSONArr.length(); i++) {
                          JSONObj = (JSONObject) JSONArr.get(i);
                          bundleResult.putString(String.valueOf(i), JSONObj.toString());
                          // System.out.println(bundleResult.getString(i));
                      } 
                  }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, have you found some answers to your problem?

Comment: @MilosCuculovic Hi,now I need to ask you if you have found a solution?