# Parse KSoap2 response in android

Tags: android, web-services, parsing, response, ksoap2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing ksoap2 response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092424/parsing-ksoap2-response)

So I managed to call a webservice using KSoap2 in android but I can't find a way to parse the response...

```
So here's what I receive from the webservice
anyType{
WORCCategoriaSubcategoriaRecord=anyType{ssENCategoria=anyType{Id=1; Nome=Problema na rua; }; ssENSubcategoria=anyType{Id=1; Nome=Falta de acesso; Imagem=anyType{}; CategoriaId=1; }; }; 

WORCCategoriaSubcategoriaRecord=anyType{ssENCategoria=anyType{Id=1; Nome=Problema na rua; }; ssENSubcategoria=anyType{Id=2; Nome=Falta de Passadeira; Imagem=anyType{}; CategoriaId=1; }; }; 
}
```

And here's the code I'm using to call the webservice...

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        //request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        try{
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            //SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
            int elementCount = resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount();

            if(elementCount>0){
                SoapObject element;
                for(int i = 0;i<elementCount;i++){
                    element = (SoapObject)resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(i);
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there any way to parse it "easily" without having to so through every property "manually"? something like a XML parser...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here, I believe this code is optimized for working with complex types and returning arrays of complex types with KSOAP:

[Web Service That Returns An Array of Objects With KSOAP](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up automatic marshalling. Check out the links section on the ksoap2-android project for links to some tutorials.